# A 1=1 Join in Pandas

Tags: sql, pandas

I have two categorical columns in a data frame (df1). I created every combination of CatA and CatB to have the length of a date range (df2). I would like to join df1 and df2 into one data frame, so that the date range is available for every CatA and CatB combination.

How can I do this in pandas? I see the documentation for the join method only supports left, right, outer, and inner. In SQL, I would join on 1=1.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

```
CatA  |  CatB
 A        M         
 A        M
 A        M
 B        N
 B        N
 B        N
```

```
CatA   |   CatB    |  Date
 A           M         9/1/2020
 A           M         9/2/2020
 A           M         9/3/2020
 B           O         9/1/2020
 B           O         9/2/2020
 B           O         9/3/2020
```

Comment: Do you know the values of CatA, CatB and the date range ahead of time ? If so, there are much more efficient and clean ways to accomplish this task than to use pandas (e.g. itertools.product)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a Cartesian product. To accomplish this, you can do the following:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'CatA': ['A','B'], 'CatB': ['M', 'N']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['9/1/2020', '9/2/2020', '9/3/2020']})

df1['_tempkey'] = 1
df2['_tempkey'] = 1

df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='_tempkey').drop('_tempkey', axis=1)
```

```
  CatA CatB      Date
0    A    M  9/1/2020
1    A    M  9/2/2020
2    A    M  9/3/2020
3    B    N  9/1/2020
4    B    N  9/2/2020
5    B    N  9/3/2020
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `df2` already, right?

Does `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)` do what you want?

```py
df1 = pd.Dataframe(['a', 'b'])
df2 = pd.Dataframe([1,2])
pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
```

produces:

```
   0  0
0  a  1
1  b  2
```

which I think is the behavior you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In order to join on categorical columns, first ensure they don't have any nulls, like so

```
df1.dropna(axis=0, subset=['CatA'], inplace=True)
df2.dropna(axis=0, subset=['CatB'], inplace=True)
```

Then use pandas merge:

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, 
                     how='inner', # inner join will do one on one 
                     left_on='CatA', right_on='CatB', 
                     sort=False # this will improve speed in big dfs
            )
```

Notes:

- you can also provide multiple columns in `left_on` and `right_on` as a list